# How to return the highest scoring image for a given product?

Tags: php, mysql, max

I have two tables, products and product_images. I have a third table 'product_categorys' too but I'm not sure how relevant this is for the question).

In the product Images table I have a column named score as an int as well as a product_id column. I would like to select a row or rows from the product table and have the highest scoring image return also. So far I have this:

```
SELECT `products`.*, `product_categorys`.`categoryName`, `product_categorys`.`categoryDescription`, `product_images`.`thumbName`
FROM (`products`)
INNER JOIN `product_categorys` ON `products`.`categoryID` = `product_categorys`.`pid`
left JOIN `product_images` ON `products`.`pid` = `product_images`.`productID`
WHERE `products`.`vendorID` =  '14'
AND `products`.`deleted` =  0
GROUP BY `products`.`pid`
ORDER BY `title` asc
LIMIT 10
```

Which returns a product image but not the highest scoring one, I'm not sure how to go about modifying this query (This has been generated by codeigniter) to give me what I need.

What needs to be changed/added to allow the query to return the highest scoring image please ?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know it it works, but give it a try:

```
SELECT p.*, 
       pc.categoryName, pc.categoryDescription, 
       pim.thumbName, pim.score
FROM products p INNER JOIN product_categorys pc 
    ON p.categoryID = pc.pid
LEFT JOIN product_images pim 
    ON p.pid = pim.productID
WHERE p.vendorID =  '14'
  AND p.deleted =  0
  AND (pim.score = 
      (SELECT MAX(score) FROM product_images pim2 
       WHERE p.pid = pim2.productID)
   OR pim.score IS NULL)
GROUP BY p.pid
ORDER BY title ASC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thanks Marco, that's giving this error: Unknown column 'pim.id' in 'where clause'.

Comment: thanks, this works but only shows product rows that have at least one corresponding row in the images table.

Comment: Marco, you've got it bang on there, thank you very much for helping, much appreciated.